# Regex expression for multiple patterns in 1 line

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I am scraping information from a log that I need 3 elements. Another added difficulty is that I am parsing the log via `readLine()` in my java program aka one(1) line at a time. (If there is a possibility to read multiple lines when parsing let me know :) ) NOTE: I have no control over the log output format.

There are 2 possibilities of what I must extract. Either the log is nice and gives the following

*NICE FORMAT*

```
.text.rank     0x0000000000400b8f      0x351 is_x86.o
```

where I must grab `.text.rank` , `0x0000000000400b8f` , and `0x351`

Now the not so nice case: If the name is too long, it bumps everything else to the next line like is below, now the only thing after the first element is one blank space followed by a newline (\n) which gets clobbered by `readLine()` anyway.

*EVIL FORMAT* : Note each line is in a separate arraylist entry.

```
.text.__sfmoreglue 
            0x0000000000401d00       0x55 /mnt/drv2homelibc_popcorn.a(lib_a-findfp.o)
```

*Therefore what the regex actually sees is:*

```
.text.__sfmoreglue
```

*CORNER CASE FORMAT that also occurs within the log but I DO NOT want*

```
 *(.text.unlikely)
```

Finally below is my Pattern line I am currently using for the first line and `pline2` is what is used *on the next line* when group 2 *of the first line* is empty.

UPDATE: The pattern below works for the *NICE FORMAT* and *EVIL FORMAT* But now pattern `pline2` has no matches, even though on regex101.com it is correct. Link: https://regex101.com/r/vS7vZ3/9

***UPDATE2:*** I fixed it, I forgot to add `m2.find()` once I compiled the second line with Pattern pline2. Corrected code is below.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[ \\s](\\.[tex]*\\.[\\._\\-\\@a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\s*([x0-9a-f]*)[ \\s]*([x0-9a-f]*).*");

Pattern pline2 = Pattern.compile("^\\s*([x0-9a-f]*)[ \\s]*([x0-9a-f]*)\\s*[\\w\\(\\)\\.\\-]*");
```

To give a little background I am first matching the name `.text.whatever` to `m.group(1)` followed by the address `0x000012345` to `m.group(2)`  and finally the size `0xa48` to `m.group(3)`. This is all assuming the log is in the NICE format. If it is in the EVIL format I see that group(2) is empty and therefore readin the next line of the log to a temp buffer and apply the second pattern `pline2` to new line.

Can someone help me with the regex?
Is there a way I can make sure my current line (or even better, just the second grouping) is either the *NICE FORMAT* or is empty?

As requested my java code:

```
//1st line pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[ \\s](\\.[tex]*\\.[\\._\\-\\@a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\s*([x0-9a-f]*)[ \\s]*([x0-9a-f]*).*");
//conditional 2nd line pattern
Pattern pline2 = Pattern.compile("^\\s*([x0-9a-f]*)[ \\s]*([x0-9a-f]*)\\s*[\\w\\(\\)\\.\\-]*");
while((temp = br1.readLine()) != null){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(temp);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println("What regex finds: m1:"+m.group(1)+"#    m2:"+m.group(2)+"#    m3:"+m.group(3));
            if(!m.group(1).isEmpty() && m.group(2).isEmpty() && m.group(3).isEmpty()){
                //means we probably hit a long symbol name and important stuff is on the next line
                //save the name at least
                name = m.group(1);
                //read and utilize the next line
                if((temp = br1.readLine()) == null){
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("EVILline2:"+temp); //sanity check the input 
                System.out.println(pline2.toString()); //sanity check the regex
                Matcher m2= pline2.matcher(temp);
                while(m2.find()){
                       System.out.println("regex line2 finds: m1:"+m2.group(1));//+"#    m2:"+m2.group(2));
                       if(m2.group(2).isEmpty()){
                             size = 0;
                       }else{
                             size = Long.parseLong(m2.group(2).replaceFirst("0x", ""),16);
                       }

                       addr = Long.parseLong(m2.group(1).replaceFirst("0x", ""),16);
                       System.out.println("#########LONG NAME: "+name+"    addr:"+addr+"    size:"+size);
                  }
            }//end if
            else{ // assume in NICE FORMAT
                //do nice format stuff.
        }//end while
}//end outerwhile
```

An Aside, The output I currently get:

```
line: .text.c_print_results
What regex finds: m1:.text.c_print_results#    m2:#    m3:
EVIL FORMATline2:                0x00000000004001e6      0x231 c_print_results_x86.o
^\s*([x0-9a-f]*)[ \s]*([x0-9a-f]*)\s*[\w\(\)\.\-]*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
at regexTest.regex.grabSymbolsInRange(regex.java:143)
at regexTest.regex.main(regex.java:489)
```

Comment: Separate your concerns: create one regex for the nice form and a different regex for the evil form. When you've got them both working, add in [a conditional](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html) to choose between them, based on something like empty group 2 or whitespace at start of line.

Comment: @PaulHicks I am doing what you say to some degree and the question is how do accommodate 2 patterns (NICE FORMAT or just empty after the name) in 1 pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your pattern.

- 1st is the separation of first and second groups (that's why group 2 is returning null).
- You have 4 groups and you need 3
- After capturing your 3 values you can stop matching, so pattern after
  last group isn't necessary
- you need global modifier \g so it returns all matches

So, instead of your posted Regex, you can try:

```
(\\.[tex]*\\.[\\._\\-\\@a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\s*([x0-9a-f]*)[ \\s]+([x0-9a-f]*)/g
```

Tested on Regex101.com:

https://regex101.com/r/lM4bQ9/1

Other then that, a few suggestions:

- if you know your text is going to start with text, just put it on the
  pattern, don't use [tex]*, which will require a few extra work from
  the engine.
- [ \s] is the same thing of \s.
- [\._\-\@a-zA-Z0-9]* from what i understood, is basically
  everything but space, so why not just use [^\s]*

So having these in mind I would suggest you to use this pattern instead:

```
(\\.text\\.[^\\s]*)\\s*([x0-9a-f]*)\\s+([x0-9a-f]*)/g
```

Comment: First, Thanks again for your timely response! If I use your first input pattern, nothing matches to my log, but I agree that your solution looks correct. Also I simplified the [tex]* of the problem because there are other starting words I am also looking for. I'm being explicit in my coding and not simplifying as a sanity check.

Comment: Post your java code, maybe the regex is not the problem, it should have matched because it matches in the test tool

Comment: I have updated the question to include my Java Code, and also updated to have my latest patterns. FYI I did tweak your pattern a little to get rid of a corner case I was having. Just to reiterate Pattern p now works but Pattern pline2 does not.

Comment: Found the error! I forgot to call m.find() again for the 2nd line Pattern! As soon as I put it in, it was scrapping the info. Thanks again for taking a look at my question!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you somehow buddy, Cheers